# How to use multi-languages for iPhone application using MonoTouch?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

How to use multi languages for iPhone application?. Currently I used english language only. But in future I want to use around 20 to 30 languages. How to use it in iPhone development using MonoTouch?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have to create a folder for each language you are using in the format "language.lproj" (e.g. en.lproj, de.proj) - in there you have to create a file called Localizable.strings (Compile Action: Content)

The File looks like that:

```
"Name For Your String"="Translation For Your String";     // don't forget the semicolon!
```

then you can call NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString("Name For YourString", "", "")

Here's a short extension method which makes the translation a little easier:

```
public static class Extension
{
   public static string t(this string translate)
   {
      return NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString(translate, "", "");
   }
}
```

you use it that way:

```
// don't forget the using

"My String".t();
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. So i need to translate all english word manually for this. right? Is there any other way? how about google translate?

Comment: You could copy only the untranslated string and translate them, but I would just use english instead of google translations 

For the translation per word, there are various translation services that you pay per word they translate.

Comment: I used dynamic words. Basically all the values coming from server only. If user wants to change the language means i need to change within the application. I don't want to call the server again for this.

Comment: If everything is from a server just translate the words on you server and pass a language variable when loading the dynamic words

Comment: Thanks for the rundown. This simple information was surprisingly tricky to find.

Comment: Using Monotouch 6, I had to put the XX.lproj folders inside a folder called "Resources" and set their build action to "BundleResource".

Comment: Also, if you want to add translated images, you can put them into a folder calles "Images" inside of the respective XX.lproj folder

Comment: Great Solution, thanks. I've a litte improvement: I've put all the strings as readonly in a static class called Constants. Then I only need to call the static string from there and have no hard-coded literals and only one place in the whole solution where all strings are. **Example: Constants.LocalizeStringMainHeader.t()**