# Is there google translate API for iPhone application?

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios, google-translate

I developed iPhone application using MonoTouch. I need to integrate multi language support (at least 20 to 30 language). And I already discussed regards [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265103/how-to-use-multi-languages-for-iphone-application-using-monotouch). But I feel its taking more time to translate all english words to other languages. Because need to create proj file for each languages manually. Can I use google translate for this? Is there any API?

Comment: Just to let you know, Google have depreciated the translate API (see the note on the top of http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html )
I had read that they're considering putting out paid options but that is something to bear in mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the [Google](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html#translate)api used to [translate](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html#translate)

```
  [1]: http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html#translate 

    https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?parameters

    https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&q=hello%20world&source=en&target=de
https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/languages?parameters
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you register for the API key, you can simply use FGTranslator in your app: https://github.com/gpolak/FGTranslator